# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/EntityRegion configuring EHCache

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, configuration, ehcache

I'm trying to add `ehcache` (v2.6.0) to my `Hibernate 4.1.5.SP1` project, but having some configuration issues.  Specifically, I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: `org/hibernate/cache/EntityRegion` error when I try and build my `Hibernate` configuration with

```
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

Here's my *Maven* dependencies ...

```
    <hibernate.version>4.1.5.SP1</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <ehcacheVersion>2.6.0</ehcacheVersion>
    ...
    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ehcacheVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here's the Java code I use to configure it ...

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration()
        .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myprojectTestDb")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "sa")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true")
        .setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider")
        .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop")
        .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
        .setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread")
        .setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true")
        .setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory")
        .addAnnotatedClass(Organization.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(State.class) 
        .addAnnotatedClass(Country.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(Domain.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(Community.class);
    final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

and here's the hideous error.  WHat configuration am I missing?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/EntityRegion
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
    at org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.service.OrganizationServiceTest.setupOrgServiceTest(OrganizationServiceTest.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.EntityRegion
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

ehcache-core files are basically for Hibernate 3.x. Hibernate 4.x comes with its own implementation for ehcache. You don't need to use ehcache explicitly in hibernate 4.x. Here is the best answer for your problem.

http://web.archive.org/web/20130117102553/http://www.javacraft.org/2012/03/migrate-to-hibernate-4-ehcache.html

Comment: The problem with this approach (using hibernate-ehcache dependency instead of ehcache-core) is this: As of time of writing this comment, the most recent version of hibernate-ehcache (4.2.0.CR2) depends on ehcache-core in version 2.4.3 according to [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.2.0.CR2). This is causing exception like "Element  does not allow attribute "maxEntriesLocalHeap", because this attribute (similarly to new <persistence> inner elements, that you define in your ehcache.xml file) have been added just recently in Ehcache (2.6.x).

Comment: The workaround is to exclude ehcache-core transitive dependency from hibernate-ehcache in your pom and add ver 2.6.x dependency on Ehcache instead.

Comment: The page with the answer gives a 404, thus this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @bluefeet♦ Thanks for updating broken link with working one. @Tapas +1 for link.

Comment: web archive kind find it (anymore). Link broken again.

Answer (score 7):

I checked maven the dependencies.
Maven always loads ehcache-code when the hibernate-ehcache package is loaded.

Dependency tree:

```
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.0.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.0.Final (*)
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.3
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 -> 1.6.6
```

Please check your persistence configuration.
It should not include any classes where the package name starts with "net.sf"

For example, you have to replace the following string in your code:

```
.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory")
```

with the following string:

```
.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Configuration.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", 
                     "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory")
```

For Hibernate 4, use

```
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory instead of net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

[Hibernate Configuration Article](https://terracotta.org/generated/4.2.0/html/bmg-all/index.html#page/BigMemory_Go_Documentation_Set/co-hib_enable_second_level_cache_settings.html)

Answer (score 1):

From Hibernate 4, there s new hibernate-cache introduce for caching. This need latest dependency for `net.sf.ehcache` upto 2.6. Following article will [CLICK ON LINK](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-4-and-ehcache-higher).
When i add following dependency in my pom, the error will remove:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
```