# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/TimestampsRegion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, caching

I am trying to implement hibernate 2nd level cache in my application.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Are those versions compatible with each other? One is `4.1.5` and the other is `4.3.8`.

Comment: @kayaman: I don't know as i am working on it first time.

Comment: Well, maybe you should find out. A class is missing and your libraries differ by 2 minor versions. What do you think that means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905722/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-cache-entityregion-configuring-ehc (implying a version conflict)

Answer (score 2):

from hibernate 4, in persistance.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
```